# How to trigger specific stage in a scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I use the `when` directive found in the declarative syntax to work for a scripted pipeline? I haven't been able to find good docs for this.

```
        // Don't run this stage if the build was triggered by cron
        when {
            triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripted pipeline is essentially a Groovy script with couple of classes/objects injected. So instead of `when` basically use `if`.

Comment: but I don't see a `trigger` property that I can run a conditional against.